# Doxygen - documenting X Macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, documentation, doxygen

I'm using Doxygen version 1.8.11 and trying to doc my X macro:

```
#define COLOR_VARIABLES\
COLOR__X(RED /*!< "RED COLOR" */)\
COLOR__X(BLUE /*!< "BLUE COLOR" */)\
```

Then I use it in an enum:

```
/** COLOR doc */
typedef enum {
  #define COLOR__X(name) name,
     COLOR_VARIABLES
  #undef COLOR__X

} color;
```

I have the MACRO_EXPANSION and ENABLE_PREPROCESSING set to YES and the `@file` at the beginning of my file.

I'd like the HTML created with the doxygen to show the documentation for each variable defined with the x macro. Can it be done?

**Edit**:

So after some suggestions here, I noticed that in my doxyfile I have the following configurations:

```
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
PREDEFINED             = INNER_FUNC(msg)=
```

If I change the `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` to No it will work but it causes other problems in my project. I have tried to do the following options but it didn't work:

Option 1:

```
PREDEFINED             = INNER_FUNC(msg)= /
                        COLOR__X(name)=name, /
                        COLOR__X:=COLOR__X
```

Option 2:

```
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = COLOR__X(name) /
                        COLOR__X
```

Comment: deos this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499422/x-macro-breaks-doxygen-callgraph ?

Comment: Your question describes what you want to do, but not why it fails. Please provide information on how your approach fails to do what you intend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X-macro breaks doxygen callgraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28499422/x-macro-breaks-doxygen-callgraph)

Comment: You mention: If I change the `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` to `No` it will work but it causes other problems in my project. What kind of problems?

Comment: I did what you said and changed `EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF` to `No` and fixed the other problem I had which required to add the following to the doxyfile:

`PREDEFINED             = __attribute__((x))= `
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

A bit to long for a comment. I don't see a problem (with 1.8.11 and 1.9.2).

The doxygen version 1.8.11 is from December 2015, so I would really advise you to upgrade to the current version (1.9.2)

I used:
**aa.h**

```
/// \file

#define COLOR_VARIABLES\
COLOR__X(RED /*!< "RED COLOR" */)\
COLOR__X(BLUE /*!< "BLUE COLOR" */)\

/** COLOR doc */
typedef enum {
  #define COLOR__X(name) name,
     COLOR_VARIABLES
  #undef COLOR__X

} color;
```

**Doxyfile**

```
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING = YES
QUIET = YES
```

and got as result:

[image]

This looks OK to me. Did I miss something?

Comment: When I tried to do that, the html doesn't show the enumerators, just the enum description "COLOR doc". Also I want to link to it from another function documentation and I get the error:
 `error: explicit link request to 'RED' could not be resolved (warning treated as error, aborting now)

Comment: Please show the minimal code you used (with file names) and the settings you used diffeerent from the default settings. Hard to tell what you exactly did.